# question about missing element in array

Tags: algorithm

i have  following problem   from book introduction algorithm second edition  by MIT university

problem is following

> An array A[1 . . n] contains all the integers from 0 to n except one. It would be easy
>       to determine the missing integer in O(n) time by using an auxiliary array B[0 . . n]
>       to record which numbers appear in A. In this problem, however, we cannot access
>       an entire integer in A with a single operation. The elements of A are represented
>       in binary, and the only operation we can use to access them is “fetch the j th bit
>       of A[i],” which takes constant time.
>
> Show that if we use only this operation, we can still determine the missing integer in O(n) time

please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call your missing number `M`.

You can split your array into two parts depending on whether the least significant bit of `A[i]` is a 1 or a 0. The smaller of the two parts (call it `P_1`) is at most `(n-1)/2` elements in size, and it tells you whether `M`'s least significant bit is a 1 or a 0.

Now consider the 2nd bit for the elements of `P_1`. Again, this part can be split in two, and the smaller of the two parts (`P_2`) tells you whether this bit should be a 1 or a 0.

Carry on going (`P_3`, `P_4`, ...) until you've worked out what all the bits are.

You can prove that this is `O(n)` because you are essentially looking at `n + n/2 + n/4 + ...` different individual bits in your array, and this sum is less than `2n`.

Comment: And you can do the split array part in-place, using the Dutch National Flag algorithm.

Comment: Great solution. But now I realize that it only works fine when n is a power of 2. What about other numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Python implementation:

```
def bit_at(n, bit):
    return (n>>bit) & 1

def find_missing(a, bits):

    indexes = range(len(a))
    missing = 0

    for bit in range(bits):

        ones = [i for i in indexes if bit_at(a[i], bit)==1]
        zeroes = [i for i in indexes if bit_at(a[i], bit)==0]

        if len(ones) <= len(zeroes):
            indexes = ones
            missing |= (1<<bit) 
        else:
            indexes = zeroes

    return missing

print find_missing([7,2,6,4,1,5,0], 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

    // Function to get the value of the bit at a specific position
    int bit_at(int n, int bit) {
    return (n >> bit) & 1;
    }

     // Function to find the missing integer
     int find_missing(int a[], int size, int bits) {
     int missing = 0;

     for (int bit = 0; bit < bits; bit++) {
     int ones_count = 0, zeroes_count = 0;

    // Count the number of ones and zeroes at the current bit position
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (bit_at(a[i], bit) == 1) {
            ones_count++;
        } else {
            zeroes_count++;
        }
    }

    // Update the missing integer based on the counts
      if (ones_count <= zeroes_count) {
        missing |= (1 << bit);
          }
       }

       return missing;
    }

    int main() 
    {
         int a[] = {3, 2, 7, 4, 1, 6, 0};
         int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
         int bits = 3;

         printf("%d\n", find_missing(a, size, bits));

         return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please add a brief summary of your solution at the starting of your answer for it to be helpful