# find missing integer

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [question about  missing element in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946056/question-about-missing-element-in-array)
>   [decrease runtime to O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447569/decrease-runtime-to-on)

An array A[1   n] contains all the integers from 0 to n except for one 
number which is missing . In this problem, we cannot access an entire 
integer in A with a single operation . The elements of A are represented in 
binary, and the only operation we can use to access them is “fetch the jth 
bit of A[i]”, which takes constant time .how to do it?? Can we do it in O(n) time?

Comment: Sounds homeworky, and does that mean that `A`'s elements are just strings representing an integer in binary?

Comment: @birryree please dot write anythng just for the sake of giving comment...write something which makes sense..

Comment: prp, this has been asked before (and answered) on SO. Suggest you do a search before asking questions in future: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946056/question-about-missing-element-in-array . And you might want to also consider doing your _own_ homework in future :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it in O(n). But if it's your homework, you should try yourself.

Comment: How can you do a binary search for an unknown value?

Comment: @Apalala: I expected sorted array. You are right this is not possible when array is not sorted. Thank you for this comment.