# Decrease runTime to O(n)

Tags: algorithm

I got this question for HW and I can't figure out how to do it:
An array A[1...n] contains all the integers from 0 to n except one. The array is not sorted.
In this problem, we cannot access an entire integer in A with a single operation.
The elements of A are represented in binary, and the only operation we can use to access them is "fetch the jth bit of A[i]", which takes constant time.

I have to find the missing integer in O(n) time.

The time it takes to do it mormally is O(NlgN)
(run on the N array, and fetch all the bits which are function of N - lgn bits).

How can I do it without reading all the bits?

Comment: Are there any other properties? E.g. are the numbers in the array are ordered? Else it is impossible without looking at each bit at least once.

Comment: Also, please post the solution you have now.

Comment: Hint: divide and conquer. Obviously you need to inspect some bit of all the numbers to begin with, but after you do that is it necessary to inspect the next bit of *all* the numbers again?

Comment: @Jon How is that going to help with a randomly ordered array?

Comment: @Marcin: I don't want to provide the solution.

Comment: @Jon I think you're going to have to give all of us a hint beyond "divide and conquer" given the constraints of the problem.

Comment: @Marcin: See the answer that Kaushik has unfortunately posted for consumption.

Comment: @Jon The key to that solution is not "divide and conquer" - it is the observation that one can observe discrepancies in the number of bits.

Comment: @Marcin: When examining bit `i` you are interested in half (rounded down) the entries than you were interested in when examining bit `i - 1`. If that's not divide and conquer then binary search is also not divide and conquer. How does that sound?

Comment: @Jon There's a difference between divide and conquer being a part of the solution, and it being the key to the solution. Posting a "hint" which is not the actual key to the solution is not especially helpful to anyone.

Comment: @Marcin: I 'm sorry that the hint was not helpful for you, but apparently at least two other people found it useful so "not anyone" might not be the word. Let's leave it at that.

Comment: @Jon I think you are inferring too much from a comment upvote. I'll say it again: "divide and conquer" simply does not contain enough information to solve this problem. The hard part is not realising that one must divide, but how to divide.

Comment: @Marcin: That's why it's called a **hint** and not a **solution**.

Comment: @Jon No, a hint is something that aids understanding. What you provided is a purely generic platitude.

Comment: @Marcin: Obviously you are not interested in logical discourse (did you read past the first four words of that comment?). Have a nice day.

Comment: @Jon I am interested in logical discourse. You are interested in defending your smug platitude to the death. (As an aside, your defence does not rely on logic, only on assertion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume for now that n is 2^k - 1 for some k.

Let's also look at an example where k = 3.

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

You'll notice that when there is a full set, like the one shown above, each column (each digit's place) has the same number of ones and zeros. Of course, for convenience we are showing this as sorted, but in reality, I am not stating that it is.

Let's take a look at the following list

```
000
001
010
011
100
110
111
```

We look at the first bit of all of the elements ( O(n) ) and figure out which count is less than the other.

We see that for the first bit, there is a number with the 1 in the most significant bit missing. This means that we know that our number has a one in its most significant bit.

Basically, we partition into two sets, one where the most significant bit is 1 and one where the most significant bit is 0. The smaller set shows us what bit the missing number has.

We do the same thing on the smaller partition.

Since it is O(n) + O(n/2) + O (n/4) ... it is basically O (2n) which is O (n).

**EDIT**

For the general case, refer to [the following document, bottom of page 1](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~martel/222a/samp.hw.pdf).

Basically, it involves making use of the fact that when n is not a power of two, you can take into account the fact that given n, you know exactly how many should fall under the bit=1 partition and the bit=0 partition if this was a complete set.

Comment: I think this wont work. Your algorithm works but only when you have all 3-bit words.  Just take n=6 (i.e. 7 elements), and let the missing be the 0. Then you would even have at each step the same amount of 0s and 1s. So you would have to look at each bit. Thats why I think the general divide-and-conquer approach is not working, without the assumption from the beginning (which is not given in the question).

Comment: Yes. You are correct. But if you noticed, I mentioned my original assumption that the number of elements is a power of 2 minus 1. I will adapt my solution soon to solve for this case. I'm reviewing my notes for this.